# Rails Compare same column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a search application where I need to compare two varieties from the same column in my database, but my current code is only noticing the second option. So in the code below if left at selected options it's only searching for variety option "2255".

**Form**

```
<%= form_tag vpc_search_path do %>
<%= select_tag :variety_one, options_from_collection_for_select(@variety, "variety_id", "variety_name", :selected => "2000"), include_blank: false %>

<%= select_tag :variety_two, options_from_collection_for_select(@variety, "variety_id", "variety_name", :selected => "2255"), include_blank: false %>
<% end %>
```

**Controller**

```
 def index
    all = Result.select(:variety_id)
    @variety = Variety.where(:variety_id => all).order('variety_name DESC')
  end

  def search
   if params[:variety_one] != params[:variety_two]
   @comparison = Result.where('variety_id' => params[:variety_one], 'variety_id' => params[:variety_two])
   else
   redirect_to vpc_index_url, notice: "Can't compare the same variety"
   end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's valid to put 2 conditions for the same attribute/column in a hash like that. Instead, you can pass an array of values for one attribute/column, so change your query to be:

```
@comparison = Result.where('variety_id' => [params[:variety_one], params[:variety_two]])
```

The [Query Interface Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.14/active_record_querying.html#hash-conditions) is where I go all the time to figure out how to do queries like this.